# Lost files when attempting to move

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-transfer

- two folders with identical file names but different contents
- delete some files in B
- move all files from A to B
- conflict emerges with replacing files, press X to cancel move
- files already moved from A stay in B
- ctrl+z in folder B, restores files that were originally deleted from B
- files moved from A are now lost

Is there anyway to recover from this? I thought the ctrl+z in folder B would undo the move, but I ended up losing my files.

Comment: You would need a backup to recover from the multiple changes describe above.  I use Sync Back Pro to prevent these issues

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking the shadow copy/previous versions (see https://www.ubackup.com/windows-10/shadow-copy-windows-10-4348.html)